# Weird automatic by-ref'ing in C++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, compiler-optimization

I'm writing a C harness to call a C++ API. I have the following code:

```
Boxa *tess_get_text_lines(tess_api_t *api, const bool raw_image, 
                          const int raw_padding, Pixa** pixa, int **blockids, 
                          int **paraids)
{
    return api->tess_api->GetTextlines(raw_image, raw_padding, pixa, blockids, 
                                       paraids);
}
```

I'm getting the following G++ error:

```
$ ./build_so.sh 
tesseract.cpp: In function ‘Boxa* tess_get_text_lines(tess_api_t*, bool, int, Pixa**, int**, int**)’:
tesseract.cpp:172:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetTextlines(const bool&, const int&, Pixa**&, int**&, int**&)’
tesseract.cpp:172:47: note: candidate is:
In file included from tesseract.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:376:9: note: Boxa* tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetTextlines(Pixa**, int**)
/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:376:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 5 provided
```

It's not matching my call to the correct overload. For reference, the following are the available overloads for the method being called:

```
Boxa* GetTextlines(const bool raw_image, const int raw_padding,
                   Pixa** pixa, int** blockids, int** paraids);
Boxa* GetTextlines(Pixa** pixa, int** blockids);
```

Why is my call being translated to "GetTextlines(const bool&, const int&, Pixa**&, int**&, int**&)" (with all of the by-ref'ing)?

Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the overloading.  Rename the second declaration/defintion of GetTextLines (the version you aren't calling) to be "GetTextLines2" or something else. This won't fix your problem, but will generate a better error message regarding the version of GetTextLines you are calling.

Comment: I'm calling an established library developed by a third party. I don't have control over it.

Comment: But you can modify the method declaration in the header file temporarily just to get through the ambiguous compile error.

Comment: And yet, that wouldn't be a fix, but a useless stopgap for one system.

Comment: My suggestion was to temporarily rename the other overloaded method in the header file just so you can get a better compiler error for the actual method you want to call. I suspect there's something subtle (i.e. the other method isn't actually declared) or there's a subtle parameter mismatch. But it's hard to understand that when the compiler is giving an error about the wrong overloaded method. Hide out the overloaded method and then try to compile again....

Comment: ... the subsequent compile will result in a different error message. That will give you a better clue about why the compiler can't resolve your call to GetTextLines. Fix the subsequent error that is guaranteed to exist after you hide the overloaded version of GetTextLines. Then revert the hack.  That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler isn't introducing references automatically. Instead, it's noting that the arguments you're providing are lvalues and attempting to find an overload that would work if provided reference types. (Notice that the types provided are information about the types you're passing into the function rather than the types actually in the signature of the function.)

That said, the error does give you the information you need to solve the problem. Notice that the first type it's saying is `const bool`, but the function you're trying to call takes a `tess_api_t*`. I think you may need to change the way you're calling the function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My adapter expects a tess_api_t, but not who I'm trying to call (see overloads at bottom). Thanks for your other insights though. They're helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out that though Tesseract has been around for eighteen years, the trunk version that I've been using has, against all odds, been given a number of additional overloads since the latest published, downloadable version (3.02.02) from earlier this year.

So, the answer to the reported problem is that, as @templatetypedef indicated, most likely that GCC is just decorating the variables with ampersands for the benefit of the error-message. The answer to the effective problem that I was having is simply that I'm not looking at an in-sync copy of the API headers.